# Indexing ServiceTypes with the SQL Server Type Provider

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers

I am using F# to add records to a SLQ Server table (Table1).

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<...>
let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()
let newRecord = new dbSchema.ServiceTypes.Table1()
```

Assuming Table1 has a column ID, I can assign it the value 5 in the new record as follows:

```
newRecord.ID <- 5
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to assign a value to a column at an indexed position, for example assign the value "test" to the 5th column?

Comment: The entire purpose of using the type provider is to abstract the columns into specific types.  As far as the returned `newRecord` type is concerned, there is no "columns" anymore, just named properties...

Comment: Reed, I appreciate that, but is there a way to index the named properties at run time then?

Comment: Just use ADO.Net if you need to do that - the type provider "kills" all sense of indexing.